# Singular route serving parameter :object_id instead of :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Say I have an object called invoice. In `routes.rb` I have

```
resources :invoices do
  get "pay"
end
```

When I run `rake routes`, the route is generated as

```
invoice_pay GET    /invoices/:invoice_id/pay(.:format) invoices#pay
```

and the parameter is `:invoices_id` instead of `:id`

If I use a match statement:

```
match "invoices/:id/pay" => "invoices#pay", :via => :get
```

I get:

```
  GET    /invoices/:id/pay(.:format)         invoices#pay
```

It seems to me that the route should be `pay_invoice_path(@invoice)`, however, I have not found suitable documentation on this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you are trying to do is

```
resources :invoices do
  get "pay", :on => :member
end
```

have a look at the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html